# How to toggle CSS class instantly when Svelte transition begins?

Tags: css, typescript, frontend, svelte, svelte-transition

**EDIT:** I'm on Svelte 3.55.

---

I am attempting to code a Sidebar in Svelte and have run into issue related to how Svelte transitions work with dynamic classes.

Sidebar is supposed to fly into view when a button is clicked. I am using the `transition:fly` for it. There is also a Dimmer component covering the entire screen, which fades into view during Sidebar's fly animation. To close the Sidebar user must click the Dimmer. Sidebar then flies out of view, and Dimmer fades out. And here is my problem.

Where the Dimmer is in its fade out animation, the page underneath cannot be interacted with. Clicking anywhere registers on the dimmer itself, Sidebar stops its fly out animation and jumps back into view.

I tried to solve it by appending `isFading` class to the Dimmer when the outro animation starts - the class would add `pointer-events: none` to the Dimmer when it fades out. But the class is appended with a delay and this solution simply does not work.

My code looks as follows:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { fade } from 'svelte/transition'
  import { isSidebarOpen, toggleSidebar } from '../state'

  let isOpen: boolean = false
  let isFading: boolean = false

  isSidebarOpen.subscribe((value) => (isOpen = value))
</script>

<div class="sidebar">
  {#if isOpen}
    <div
      class="sidebar__dimmer"
      class:isFading
      on:click={toggleSidebar}
      on:outrostart={() => (isFading = true)}
      on:introstart={() => (isFading = false)}
      transition:fade={{ duration: 500 }}
    />
  {/if}
  <div>Lorem opsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .sidebar {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    inset: 0;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;

    &__dimmer {
      position: absolute;
      inset: 0;
      pointer-events: all;
    }

    &__dimmer.isFading {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  }
</style>
```

My question is: how do I append the `isFading` class to the component instantly when the outro animation starts?

Comment: I hope you add/added another method of closing the side bar, because that ain't accessible.

Comment: There is a close button inside the Sidebar component. I removed that part of the code from this post because it's not relevant to the question

Comment: Cannot really reproduce this ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c334e1e667584b31bdfe452e4b46b1e2?version=4.2.0)), can click through the overlay immediately.

Comment: (That uses Svelte v4 by default, which should not need the class anyway: "the inert attribute is now applied to outroing elements to make them invisible to assistive technology and prevent interaction". Do not have any issues with v3 either, though.)

Comment: I'm on v3 - maybe there was something wrong with my setup then. I managed to overcome the issue by adding `pointer-events: none` to the parent component instead of Dimmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to overcome this issue by applying `fading` class to the `sidebar` component instead of dimmer one. I didn't need an additional variable to check if the component is transitioning - I reused the `isOpen` instead.

```
<div class="sidebar" class:fading={!isOpen}>
  {#if isOpen}
    <div
      class="sidebar__dimmer"
      on:click={toggleSidebar}
      transition:fade={{ duration: 500 }}
    />
  {/if}
  <div>Lorem opsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  // ...
  .sidebar.fading .sidebar__dimmer {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>
```

[H.B. answer also gave me an idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76913713/14164686) to add an `inert` attribute to sidebar whenever `isOpen` is false, following how the Svelte 4+ handles transitions:

```
<div class="sidebar" inert={!isOpen}>
  // ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Svelte 4 you should not need this in browsers supporting [`inert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inert), as that will be added automatically.

You could apply the class directly using the DOM via the event:

```html
<div ...
  on:outrostart={e => e.target.classList.add('isFading')}
  on:introstart={e => e.target.classList.remove('isFading')} />
```

(Might have to use `target?.`, `currentTarget` or extract logic to functions if you run into TypeScript errors.)

Since the class is applied in a way that makes it invisible to the compiler, you will have to change the selector accordingly:

```
&__dimmer:global(.isFading) ...
```

Answer (score -1):

By using the start and end transition callbacks, the isFading class will be applied instantly when the outro animation starts, and it will be removed when the outro animation ends. This should help you achieve the desired behavior where the Dimmer doesn't interfere with interactions while fading out.

```
 <script lang="ts">
      import { fly, fade } from 'svelte/transition';
      import { isSidebarOpen, toggleSidebar } from '../state';
    
      let isOpen: boolean = false;
      let isFading: boolean = false;
    
      isSidebarOpen.subscribe((value) => (isOpen = value));
    </script>
    
    <div class="sidebar">
      {#if isOpen}
        <div
          class="sidebar__dimmer"
          class:isFading
          on:click={toggleSidebar}
          transition:fade={{ duration: 500 }}
          transition:start={() => (isFading = true)}
          transition:end={() => (isFading = false)}
        />
      {/if}
      <div>Lorem opsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>
    
    <style lang="scss" scoped>
      .sidebar {
        z-index: 9999;
        position: fixed;
        inset: 0;
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
        pointer-events: none;
    
        &__dimmer {
          position: absolute;
          inset: 0;
          pointer-events: all;
        }
    
        &__dimmer.isFading {
          pointer-events: none;
        }
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: There is no such thing.